# Cannot fix Promise in react native Promise { "_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null, }

Tags: firebase, react-native

Why did I add Promise to the function it still gives an error ??

I cannot call this function again with the parameter I give ??

Get User by Uid in Fire.js file( I custom this file )

```
 getUserbyUid = async ({ Uid }) => {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection('user')
                .doc(Uid)
                .get()
                .then(documentSnapshot => {
                    res(documentSnapshot.data().name);
                })
                .catch(error => { rej(error) });
        })

    }
```

in Feed.js i call it

```
  async componentDidMount() {
        await firebase.firestore().collection("Post").get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {


                querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {

                    this.setState({ dataPost: this.state.dataPost.concat({ ...documentSnapshot.data(), 
                    key: documentSnapshot.id, }) })
                    console.log(Fire.shared.getUserbyUid(documentSnapshot.data().uid)); <= error this if i console.log(documentSnapshot.data().uid)) it will return a Uid 

but If i call in above it will return  Promise { "_U": 0,"_V": 0, "_W": null,"_X": null,}


                });
            });
    }
```